# Conditional equation with two-sided curly brackets

Tags: equations, brackets

[image]
Hello, in my document I want to include an equation of the following form. I couldn't find any solution for that. Is this possible and do you know how to do it? Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Here is the code which I created by using Zarko's Ansatz:

```
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma_h=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) \\  
\sigma_k=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3})\\
\end{array}
\rightarrow  
\begin{cases}
\begin{rcases}  
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{k_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\end{rcases} &   \text{with prop. $\frac{r}{2(3-1)}$} \\[5ex]
\begin{rcases} 
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\end{rcases} &   \text{with prop. $\frac{1-r}{2}$}
\end{cases} 
\]
```

[image]
The problem is now, that the fractions are quite small. How could I fix that?

Edit2: Got it. \dfrac solves the new emerged problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, in future show to as, what you try so far, i.e. where you stuck with LaTeX code. Otherwise your question is `do-it-instead-me`, which aren't popular here.

Comment: Use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` to have the `\frac`s in `\displaystyle` mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Obtained by nested `rcases` in `cases` math environments, both from `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
a = \begin{cases}
        \begin{rcases}  b &  \\
                        c &  \\
                        d &
        \end{rcases} &   \text{if $x > 1$} \\[5ex]
        \begin{rcases}  e &  \\
                        f &  \\
                        g &
        \end{rcases} &   \text{if $x < 1$}
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

*Addendum:*
Your fraction in updated question are in `text` mpode. To convert them to `display` mode, you need to use `dfrac` from `amsmath` or `mathtools` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma_h=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) \\
\sigma_k=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3})\\
\end{array}
\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\begin{rcases}
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{k_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\end{rcases} &   \text{with prop. $\dfrac{r}{2(3-1)}$} \\[5ex]
\begin{rcases}
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{h_1} \sigma_{h_2} \sigma_{h_3}) &  \\
\sigma_i=(\sigma_{k_1} \sigma_{k_2} \sigma_{k_3}) & \\
\end{rcases} &   \text{with prop. $\dfrac{1-r}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :). There is just one new issue which I put in the question. Could you help me there?

Comment: quit simple: instead of `\frac` you need to use `\dfrac` from `mathtools` ... I will edit ma answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\savestack\topstack{$\left.\Centerstack{c\\d\\e}\right\} \text{if $x>1$}$}
\savestack\botstack{$\left.\Centerstack{g\\h}\right\} \text{if $x<1$}$}
\left\{\!\vcenter{\hbox{\Shortstack[l]{\topstack\\ \botstack}}}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does your solution has any advantages compared that of Zarkos?

Comment: @HighwayJohn I would say that Zarko's approach uses the more standard LaTeX math tools.  For this problem, it would be more a matter of preference on your part.  There may be some unique applications for which my stacking approach may prove superior.